# How can I get this ternary operator working on cshtml page?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I found this to be a strange problem, especially since it has to do with both C# (ternary operator) and an ASP.NET Core Web App.
I have a .cshtml page that is doing a check for if the user is either Editing a restaurant or Creating a new one. I used a ternary operator here to cut down on space for the page.
Here's the troubling area on my page Edit.cshtml:

```
@{
(Model.RestaurantOnPage.Id < 1) ? <h2>Creating new restaurant</h2> : <h2>Editing @Model.RestaurantOnPage.Name</h2>; 
}
```

The error:

> CS1525: Invalid expression term ':'

Here's the actual error's meaning: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1525
I don't see where this issue is coming from. I also don't ask many questions on StackOverflow, so sorry if this question is a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right form of using your `ternary operator` is :

```
 <h2>
        @((condition)? action1: action2)
 </h2>
```